# how to procses Cloudflare Turnstile in web driver with selenuim

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

i try to use selenuim module to get for some website unsuccsesfull.
this is what i try:
undetected_chromedriver
add user profile
use proxy.
when i open it with webdriver the Cloudflare not allow me to process.
when i open it with normal chrom its works fine.
any idias?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from datetime import datetime
import time
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print('Hey Elior, im on = ', current_time)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 12")

driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

def login():
    driver.get("site")
    # identify username, password and signin elements
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").click()
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys('')

    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").click()
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys('')

    time.sleep(1)
    # press on login button
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-submit").click()

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.execute_script("console.clear()")  # clean the console
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem and i used the library undetected-chromedriver to resolve.
Just try the code below in simple way.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


import undetected_chromedriver as uc


driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('website')
```

Here's an example straight from the library: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/blob/master/example/example.py

Comment: he already use the undetected_chromedriver